# Trying to insert value in class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, methods

I'm trying to pass an argument from the get_name() to post() and I'm not sure how to do this correctly

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

webhook = 'my webhook'

class Item:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.page = requests.get(url)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page.content, 'html.parser')

    def post(self):
        requests.post(webhook, json={'username' : 'scraper', 'content' : variable}) #how do i do this

    def get_name(self):
        name = self.soup.find('h2').get_text()
        post(name)

    def get_price(self):
        price = self.soup.find('span' {'class' : 'text-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render'})
        post(price)
```

Comment: Assign to `self.name` in `get_name()` and use `self.name` in `post()`

Comment: But how should I go about doing this, because I will have multiple functions like get_name, get_price, get_description

Comment: How do they relate to `post()`?

Comment: You need to edit the question and explain in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'll repeat that: Edit the question, don't answer in comments.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean I get data using get_name() and get_price and post the data using the post()

Comment: But how is should `name` and `price` be used used in `post()`? If you have multiple functions, how do you want to combine all their results when you call `post()`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want something like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

webhook = 'my webhook'

class Item:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.page = requests.get(url)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page.content, 'html.parser')

    def post(self, data):
        requests.post(webhook, json={'username' : 'scraper', 'content' : data}) 

    def get_name(self):
        name = self.soup.find('h2').get_text()
        self.post(name)
```

Comment: where should I change the data in get_name()

Comment: This does not work : post(name)
NameError: name 'post' is not defined

Comment: Did you change `post(name)` to `self.post(name)`?

Answer (score 0):

The `self` in the class means that any variable/attribute attached to self can be accessed by any function attached to self anywhere inside the class scope. This means that you are not passing arguments to parameters of a function but instead you use the `self` identifier.

So with your code the variable and function calls inside the functions are local to the function. To give the variable class scope, attach them to `self`. eg

```
    def get_name(self):
        name = self.soup.find('h2').get_text()
        post(name)
```

would become

```
    def get_name(self):
        self.name = self.soup.find('h2').get_text()
        self.post()
```

then in `def post(self):` you would reference `self.name` to process.

Answer (score 0):

Two (maybe three) problems:

1. `post` is not a function the enclosing scope; it is a class attribute of the class `Item`, and needs to be accessed as such from `Item` or an instance of `Item`.
2. `post` needs to take an additional argument to be used as the value of the `content` key.
3. `Item.post` should probably return the return value of `requests.post`, as the caller may want to that in order to, for example, check the result of the POST request.

Your class should look like

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.page = requests.get(url)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page.content, 'html.parser')

    def post(self, variable):
        return requests.post(webhook, json={'username' : 'scraper', 'content' : variable})

    def get_name(self):
        name = self.soup.find('h2').get_text()
        self.post(name)

    def get_price(self):
        price = self.soup.find('span' {'class' : 'text-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render'})
        self.post(price)
```